# Problema ChildEventListener() no carga datos?

Tags: java, firebase

**Hola mundo.**

Mi problema consiste en que mis métodos escuchas nunca reciben ni cargan datos, existiendo datos en esa referencia de base de datos **usando la sdk o libreria de Firebase Admin para JAVA**.

**Mi código:**

```
 try{
        
    FileInputStream refreshToken = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ABRAHAM-JOSE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\botWHAST\\src\\json\\bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-9b99ace819.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://bot-whatsapp-1d730.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    System.out.println("si carga firebase");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("no carga firebase");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("repartidores");
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
          
          if(!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("nulo")){  
            repartidor newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(repartidor.class);
            System.out.println("tlf: " + newPost.getTLF());
            System.out.println("cliente: " + newPost.getCliente());
            System.out.println("estado: " + newPost.getEstado());
            System.out.println("nombre: " + newPost.getNombre());
            System.out.println("Previous Post ID: " + prevChildKey);
            
              repartidores.add(newPost);
              pan.actualizar_chats(repartidores);  
           
          }else{
              System.out.println("nulo es reconocido");
          }
          
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println(databaseError);
        }
  });
```

El anterior código declara y conecta perfectamente mi **APP jAVA** con **FIREBASE**, pero la momento de proseguir a obtener los datos mediante el método **ChildEventListener()** no imprime nada, ni siquiera un misero error. El código debería de obtener los datos de la referencia en el objeto **repartidor** y excluir un **key** llamado **nulo**. Y por ultimo actualiza una **jList** en un **jFrame**.

Pero no pasa nada, ya no se que hacer **:-(**.

La clase **repartidor:**

```
public class repartidor {
    private int estado;//0=Desactivado 1=Activo 2=ocupado
    private String tlf;
    private String tlf_cliente;
    private String nombre;
    
    repartidor(String tlf, String cliente, int estado, String nombre){
        this.estado = estado;
        this.tlf = tlf;
        this.tlf_cliente = cliente;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public void setCliente(String n){
        this.tlf_cliente = n;
    }
    public String getCliente(){
        return this.tlf_cliente;
    }
    
    public void setEstado(int estado){
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    public int getEstado(){
        return this.estado;
    }
    
    public void setTLF(String n){
        this.tlf = n;
    }
    public String getTLF(){
        return this.tlf;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
}
```

Mi estructura de **Base de Datos:**

> Mi Base de Datos
>
> -repartidores
>
> --nulo: "nulo"
>
> --tlf1
>
> ---tlf: "Numero de tlf"
>
> ---estado: 1
>
> ---cliente: "tlf cliente"   nombre: "julio"
>
> --tlf2
>
> ---tlf: "Numero de tlf"
>
> ---estado: 1
>
> ---cliente: "tlf cliente"
>
> ---nombre: "Mario"
>
> ...

La estructura de base de datos consiste en lo siguiente mi base de datos tiene un nodo secundario o hijo llamado **repartidores** y este a su vez se divide en sub-hijos, tiene un hijo estático llamado **nulo** y varios hijos que se van cargando en forma de lista cuyo **ID** es un numero de **teléfono**. Estos hijos en forma de lista se dividen en 3 campos que quiero recuperar un **estado** que almacena un **numero entero**, un **numero de teléfono** o **tlf** donde se almacena una **cadena** con un numero telefónico, un **cliente** en este se almacena también un **tlf** en una **cadena** y por ultimo un **nombre** en donde se encuentra el **nombre** del repartidor.

Gracias y **espero su pronta ayuda.**

Comment: Diste los permisos de internet en tu manifest ? Podrias publicar la estructura de la base de datos ?

Comment: Hola amigo, no estoy desarrollando una app móvil, sino una app de escritorio y por donde tengo entendido no debo colocar ese tipo de permiso y menos en Windows, ya edite mi pregunta. Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: tendras la estructura de tu base de datos ?

Comment: ya la agregue, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: no se entiende esa estructura, no se sabe si son nodos o hijos, deberias exportar el json y ponerlo aqui , o poner una foto